# Company tries to retain an hard working but brash employee by treating me in an unfair way

Tags: management, colleagues, resignation, unprofessional-behavior, politics

EDIT:

Because of the repeated requested by people to stay concise I am editing the question.

I joined a company, a colleague of mine has been really unprofessional to me.Lot of times shouting at me. Blocking me from working and really making it difficult to work.

In the meanwhile, a new manager comes in. I was taken aback when he pretty much was rationalising this bad behaviour.

I raise the issue with the ceo. He also seems to be aligned with the ceo.

Later I realise that this colleague of mine is related to the ceo.

The ceo organises a patchup call, i resign from job, since it would not make sense to do the right thing?

Do you guys agree?

Comment: I was fedup, so i resigned and have now got a new job.

Comment: You did right in resigning, and finding a new job quickly enough proves it. Best wishes.

Comment: There is no question here?

Comment: @Erik I read “was I right in resigning” as a question...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. This is a Q&A site, not a forum- we're about asking questions and giving answers rather than discussion.

Comment: Welcome to The Workplace @Bad bones. As you've seen your question wasn't that well received and while I appreciate your edits to drastically shorten this down, as long as your question comes down to "*Was this the right call?*" it won't be a great fit here. You made a judgement call based on how you felt about your job and we can't really put ourselves in your shoes, no matter how much info you provide. We tend to cover specific questions on how to handle a workplace situation or come to a decision on a practical problem. Feel free to check out the [tour] and [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You post is very unnecessarily long.  It could be summarized as this:

"I worked for a very dysfunctional company that was unwilling to change so I left".

It happens all the time and might happen to you again in the future.  No need to get upset about it, just move on and hopefully improve your compensation package in the process.  Software developers should be thankful that there is a lot of mobility in their careers, and changing jobs (even in a short time) is not seen as a blight.  Sometimes a job is so dysfunctional that it is accepting a lower compensation package is acceptable just to move on.

The best "revenge" is resigning with a smile on your face and saying nothing during the exit interview.  Then going on and doing great things at another company.

Answer (score 2):

I am going to pose a frame challenge here.

Your question oozes with highly biased judgement that favors yourself over anyone else, and there are several cases of needless emphatics.

### Self-aggrandizement

> They hired me as senior engineer, and my performance was excellent to say the least. I have saved the company lot of money, by bringing to life things they had given up on.

It's one thing to say your work was well reviewed by the company. It's another to label yourself "excellent to say the least". "saved the company lot of money, by bringing to life things they had given up on" sounds near-messianic.

### This is textbook [ad hominem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_hominem)

Then you go on to describe the people you work with:

- The engineer in focus is beyond "unprofessional". I say "beyond" because you specifically point out that "calling him unprofessional would be an understatement"
- The CTO is "weak"
- The senior manager is "from the 80's"
- The manager is doing "weird" politics, like approaching people, talking to them, and being on the same side (???)

Gosh, it seems like everyone except you is incompetent.

I especially got a chuckle from your description of the senior manager:

> And after all this tries to pretend as if he is doing a great job, and everyone should be grateful to him.

...because that is *exactly* how I interpret your description of yourself, and how you seem to expect people to respond to your input about developer X.

### Clear bias leads to a lack of trust

**I am not interested in arguing details with you** about who said what. But I am very strongly inferring here that you are presenting a biased story where you've not particularly tried to remain objective or pragmatic, which in turn leads me to wonder how this narrative has been spun, and where the more objective origin lies.

It seems to me that you are adamant about your opinion on how a company should operate being the only correct one. This is clear from your descriptions of others. You state (alleged) fact, and every time implicitly rely on the "and this is not how you should do it" inference, as if there's one universally agreed upon way of doing things.

This approach of yours especially goes off the rails when describing the manager. Other than you subjectively labeling it as "weird", there is *nothing* in your list of his actions that even remotely argues that this manager is not performing their job.
Your interpretation of their alleged "mantra" is *even by your own claims* based on rumors and inference.

There is nothing substantive about any of the people you've described, even though you've gone to great lengths to paint them in a negative spotlight. This significantly backfires for you. Rather than prove just how much better you are, it shows you as a petty, vindictive and fiercely competitive employee, none of which are admirable traits.

### Vagueness to avoid substance

> He starts shouting at meeting, prevents me from sometimes doing my job and asking for unreasonable changes in the code.

It's an odd coincidence that I've had almost the exact same complaints levied against me from specific coworkers (in different workplaces I was detached to). Which allows me to put the spotlight on how vague and subjective these claims are. Using my personal example:

- The unreasonable changes? Using commonly agreed upon good practice development strategies that this developer refused to learn (concretely: writing tests and documentation, promoting loose coupling and encapsulation)
- Preventing them from doing their work? Well, these "useless" good practices eat up all the time they could spend on writing (bad practice) code and the dozens of bugs they need to fix (due to bad practice development)
- Shouting at meetings? Well, I refused to keep letting them devolve any meeting into arguing whether we should employ good practice for *every* meeting, no matter the topic of the meeting. I did not shout or lose my cool, but I did assertively shut down these constant distractions and cyclic discussions.

I'm not claiming my experience precisely matches your experience, but given the emphatic nature of your descriptions and your unwillingness to do things any way other than how you think they need to be done (as inferred by me), this example shows just how much vagueness there is in your concrete problems with this alleged "bad apple" on your team.

I am strongly convinced that your persistent vagueness about concrete problems (both about this developer and in your description of why all your managers are incompetent) is a **conscious effort to twist the argument in your favor**. The way you structure your arguments, leave conclusions up to implicit inference, and emphatically describe anything you disagree with as unfavorable makes it really hard to convince me otherwise.

### The workplace is about communication, not just work

The goal of this answer is not to argue with you, but rather to help you overcome the obstacle in the workplace that you're faced with. I *genuinely* want to help you and make your work experience better. However, it seems like the obstacle is not what you think it is.

I'm not claiming that you're wrong about whatever the original disagreement (which you did not explain) was. I can't arbitrate on things you don't mention, but I want to make it clear that I'm not saying that I think you're wrong about literally everything.

What I am certain of, is that your attitude is at best selfishly biased and unfair towards your coworkers, and at worst it is downright toxic. Over all, **this makes you the bad apple**.

Think of it this way: how likely is it that *you alone* are more correct in assessing this developer and how they function within the company, when *three* people (CTO, senior manager, manager) all evaluate this developer completely differently?

I'm not saying it's impossible you're right, but I would expect *some* level of humility and a proper argumentation as to why you think the other three people are wrong. In this answer, you have only resorted to attacking their character with unsubstantiated judgmental descriptors. There is not a shred of substantive argument as to why these people's evaluation might be misguided.

Your biased-bordering-on-toxic attitude is likely at the root of why your input is being on this developer is being ignored.

Based on personal experience in many workplaces, often those with endemic issues (as a consultant, I am often detached to workplace that have gone awry to fix things), I suspect that what has happened here is that there has been a genuine but harmless disagreement, and that you've doubled down on your position several times since then, leading to this escalated scenario where you no longer present it as just a disagreement, but almost to being a conspiracy of an entire company filled with incompetent people who are all working together to exclude you.

### The conclusion

If you genuinely feel that everyone is as incompetent as you say they are, they you're either going to have to learn to live with the incompetence, or find a new place to work. You're not going to be able to single-handedly run the place, no matter how right you may have been about the original issue.

However, if the problem is rooted in your attitude, at least the part that turned a harmless disagreement into an alleged "conspiracy of the incompetent", then this problem is going to repeat itself wherever you work. It's time to learn to trust in others, and have some humility about your own opinions.

I have *plenty* of opinions that are different from how my company operates, but I choose to not die on these hills. I do my job and provide input to the degree my input is desired. My personal opinions on how certain things should be done, I limit to either professional projects where I do get free reign or personal projects where I can do it my way.

And as much as you may think your opinions are better, most developers who I've talked to who did things their own way in personal projects sometimes do realize that their approach had a significant flaw that they had not yet spotted.

Humility is not weakness, it is strength.

Comment: ,I tried my best to provide as much context as possible for anyone to have a fair judgement, 
I was particularly taken aback when you describing Mr X's unreasonable requests had already implied that I was not adhering to good practices or am not a major proponent of it. 
I can assure you here that , it is not the case. 
Moreover it seems like you have written this with the experience of someone who has been a Mr X in that past. 
All I would say is be nice and humble.

Comment: As to being humble, I consider it as one of my greatest virtues. Although I would have to let you know that with being humble you do not have to disregard the flaws in other which are obvious and need correction for the relation to work better. It is also important to know when you are right, to stand up for yourself. Only then does humility count.

Comment: There is a reason why 4 people before me left

Comment: You are not answering the question, it seems like you are biased yourself. You got almost the same complaints against you from some coworkers, and you think you know exactly what kind of person the OP is. It's like you're telling him what you couldn't tell your coworkers. It's almost like you're projecting.

Comment: @Doliprane: The only question asked here is "do you guys agree?" My answer very much responds that I do not. Also, it seems like you missed the purpose of the breakdown into the individual complaints. Every complaint OP levied is devoid of concrete facts, in a way that _anything_ can be argued to lie at the basis. "This is a distraction from my work" is something you could say about _literally anything_ that you weren't already doing, regardless of whether it's good or bad. _That_ is what I'm pointing out. If you want to call passing experience on as projection, good luck to you then.

Comment: @Badbones _"As to being humble, I consider it as one of my greatest virtues."_ I sincerely hope you realize the irony.

Comment: @Flater, In your reply you strongly advocated being humble and to be sensitive to people. But I must tell you that your message was in itself against humility, your way of telling someone to be humble in a very demeaning way was kind of ironic.

Comment: @Badbones: You can keep arguing your point, and I suspect that you will keep doing so. Incessant arguing is part of this negative/toxic attitude I've been trying to point out. I'm not interested in you shifting goalposts or trying to turn arguments around on people to avoid having to acknowledge what you're being told. Your original question had all the markers for a severe lack of humility, and I'm not changing my observation just because you start arguing about my humility.

Comment: @Flater I am not even to remotely trying to change your opinion about me. I am just trying to help you and the society by letting you know your flaws which need to be improved. Writing a long essay, teaching about humility is a nice thing, but you need to also make sure that in that process you are also being humble.

Comment: @Badbones I'm not interested in you trying to turn arguments around on people to avoid having to acknowledge what you're being told. And this is the last response from me.